# how to allow user to enter the password 3 times in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm working in this program for 3 hours but i do not know where I'm doing wrong .If you could help i really appreciate it . The problem is when i'm  entering the password .It says it is wrong password even if i put the right password  it does not allows me to retry again .The program suppose to allows the user to try  3 times if the users puts wrong password after third time the program has to close  .

```
public partial class UserAndPin : Window
{
    public UserAndPin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Customer.txt");

            short attempts = 0;
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] lineArray = line.Split(';');
                if (lineArray[0] == txtName.Text & lineArray[1] == pbPassword.Password)
                {
                    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                    this.Hide();
                    mainWindow.ShowDialog();
                    //return;
                }
                else
                {
                    attempts++;
                    if (attempts < 3)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The NAME or PIN is incorect, you have " + (3 - attempts) + " attemps more");                                                    
                    }
                    if (attempts == 3)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please try again later");
                        this.Close();
                    }                        
                }                    
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Learn to use your debugger!  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Gurwinder Can you explain me a bit more what u mean please ?

Comment: @Gurwinder What's wrong with using `==` to compare strings?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx

Comment: Because you are comparing the password from the first line of the txt file, thus the logic only works for the first user.

Comment: @Eric Even the first one does not work bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> loginInfo;
short attempts = 0;

public UserAndPin()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Load the file to the dictionary
    loginInfo = File.ReadAllLines("Customer.txt")
        .Select(i => i.Split(';')) // Lines format: Username;Password
        .ToDictionary(i => i[0].ToLower(), i => i[1]);  // Username is the key of the dictionary

}

private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    var userId = txtName.Text.ToLower(); // Username ignore case
    var password = pbPassword.Password;

    if (loginInfo.ContainsKey(userId) && loginInfo[userId] == password)
    {
        // login success, show main window
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        this.Hide();
        mainWindow.ShowDialog();
        return;
    }

    // login fail, increment the count only
    attempt++;

    if (attempts < 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The NAME or PIN is incorect, you have " + (3 - attempts) + " attemps more");                                                    
    }
    if (attempts == 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please try again later");
        this.Close();
    }   

}
```

Comment: The `while` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring the `short attempts = 0;` inside the `btnOK_Click` everytime you click the button will initiate the `attempts` to be `0` whereas you want it to be increased by 1 everytime the user clicks the button thus you need to declare it globally like

```
public partial class UserAndPin : Window
{
    short attempts;
    public UserAndPin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        attempts = 0;
    }
```

`attempts++;` should be below the while loop because if you have 10 user info in the file it will add or increment the `attempt` every time the condition doesnt match.

Now if the username and password doesnt match from the file you are reading. which obviously doesnt match if the user info is at 10th position or line it will give you message box for 9 times. Another issue is `Logical AND operator` it is `&&` and not `&` and than it would match so the correct way should be

```
public partial class UserAndPin : Window
{
    short attempts;
    public UserAndPin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        attempts = 0;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Customer.txt");
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] lineArray = line.Split(';');
                if (lineArray[0] == txtName.Text && lineArray[1] == pbPassword.Password)
                {
                    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                    this.Hide();
                    mainWindow.ShowDialog();
                    //return;
                }
            }
            sr.Close();

            if (attempts < 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The NAME or PIN is incorect, you have " + (3 - attempts) + " attemps more");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please try again later");
                this.Close();
            }
            attempts++; //Since user has attempted it.
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is still the issue that `attempts`should be incremented outside the while.

Comment: Yup!! @Kinetic. Thanks for the catch

Comment: ...and both `if`where he is checking `attempts` value should not be in the `while`.  But this is pretty close.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava thank you for taking  your time answering my question .But still does not work bro

Answer (score 1):

You should initilize the 'attempts ' every authentication successfully. Or more than 3 times in 3 hours.

If you login in success at 2 times then the 'attempts' should be 0.

If the project rejects you log in over than 3 hours, the 'attempts' also should be set to 0.

Comment: Where is that 3 hours coming from?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read your file to get all user name and password.  Ideally, you would do this only once in the constructor.

Then, you need to increment your counter by one.  And this counter needs to be declared outside the click event handler like stated in other answers.

Finally, you can then check if the user/password entered match one from the file.  if it does, you can open your form.  If not, you show one of the message box depending if the user has reached the third attempt or not.

```
public partial class UserAndPin : Window
{
    short attempts;

    public UserAndPin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        attempts = 0;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {   
            var users = File.ReadAllLines("Customer.txt")
                .Select(line => new { login = line[0], password = line[1] })
                .ToList();

            attempts++;

            if (users.Any(user => user.login == txtName.Text && user.password == pbPassword.Password))
            {
                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                this.Hide();
                mainWindow.ShowDialog();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (attempts < 3)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The NAME or PIN is incorect, you have " + (3 - attempts) + " attemps more");
                }
                if (attempts >= 3)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please try again later");
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```